# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS VGA Monitor Resolution Problem

Tags: display, intel, display-resolution, xrandr

I have a VGA monitor and Intel graphic card. The system shows only 1024x768 and 800x600 resolution sizes. I am trying to set the resolution of my display manually as 1920x1080. I set it previously as 1280x1024 but now I am getting an error. Here is my terminal output:

```
:~$ xrandr
```

Output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1024 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA1 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00* 
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Then:

```
:~$ cvt 1920 1080
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
:~$ xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
:~$ xrandr --addmode VGA1 1920x1080_60.00
:~$ xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1920x1080_60.00
```

The resolution not changed and the error is:

```
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
```

I tried to run intel-linux-graphics-installer but it failed also. How can I fix this problem?